# Discord.js DiscordAPIError: Two factor is require for this operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been using this sudo command in my test server and it works well but when I tried to use it in another server, I keep getting the `DiscordAPIError: Two factors are required for this operation` error.
Any way on how to fix this?

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'sudo',
  description: 'sudo webhook',
  userpermissions: ['MANAGE_WEBHOOKS'],

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!args[1])
      return message.reply(
        'Please provide a message to send \n ```\n usages: sudo [mention] [text]```'
      );
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!member) return message.reply('Please tag a user');
    message.channel
      .createWebhook(member.user.username, {
        avatar: member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
      })
      .then((webhook) => {
        webhook.send(args.slice(1).join(' '));
        setTimeout(() => {
          webhook.delete();
        }, 3000);
      });
  },
};
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable two factor authentication on your own account for this action to work. Go into your user settings -> my account and click "Enable Two-Factor Auth". After following the steps you're prompted with everything should work fine.

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/219576828-Setting-up-Two-Factor-Authentication

Comment: I already had my account 2FA enabled. Still, it didn't work even when my account has 2FA enabled.

Comment: @Heko Are you absolutely sure that 1) you have 2FA enabled and 2) you own the bot?

Comment: Yes. I kicked the bot and invited it again and its working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 2FA enabled on the guild/account and it is asking since you're creating a webhook.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with 2FA enabled?