# Discord Bot - "403 Forbidden" error with purge and other administrator commands although 2FA was set up

Tags: python, discord

When I try to execute my Python script, the terminal reports an error message:

> 403 Forbidden (error code: 60003): Two factor is required for this operation

But I have already a 2FA security in my Authentication App.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
print(client)

@client.command()
async def clear(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

client.run("token")
```

I tried to search in my discord settings on Privacy & Setting, but I think there are no problems in here.

In my developer page of discord, I gave on my bot the Administrator Role.

Comment: Why the git tag ?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have this problem with other commands?

Comment: Comments on [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004146/discord-js-discordapierror-two-factor-is-require-for-this-operation) indicate you may have to kick the bot and have it re-join after you've enabled 2FA.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I have this problem with only commands like ban , kick ex.. Administrator commands

Comment: @esqew Man, in my server ds i have already enabled the 2FA.

Comment: Now WORKK, I dont know why!!