# Why do i need 2FA to delete a discord message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Alright so basically.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class ssupy(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def ssu(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator or any(role.name == "testie" for role in ctx.author.roles):
            channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=1039997170025234512)
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Server SSU!",
                description="> Denver city has started a ssu, for a quick entry click the link above.",
                colour=discord.Colour.green()
            )
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.send(content="SSU successfully started!", ephemeral=True, delete_after=5)
            try:
                await ctx.message.delete()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred while deleting the message: {e}")
        else:
                await ctx.send(content="You do not have the permissions to run this command.", ephemeral=True, delete_after=5)
                await ctx.message.delete()

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(ssupy(client))
```

This is my code, everything works perfectly but the command just does not delete the invoked command.

`Error: An error occurred while deleting the message: 403 Forbidden (error code: 60003): Two factor is required for this operation`

I expected it to delete the command that was executed.

Comment: As the error suggest you'll need to activate 2-factor authorization on your account

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a policy decision, not a technical problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js DiscordAPIError: Two factor is require for this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004146/discord-js-discordapierror-two-factor-is-require-for-this-operation)

Comment: Stackoverflow is a website to solve problems and not to talk about the policy of service providers

Answer (score 1):

Many discord guilds can **enforce the 2-factor Authorization rule** in their discord guild settings, to **avoid guild raids or nukes**. And all discord guilds with the **feature "COMMUNITY"** are forced to enable it. All users, even bot owners must activate it - that's **because** your bot can't delete the message.

The bot developer - in this case, you - needs to **enable 2FA on your own account** in order to be able to delete messages with your bot on that 2FA-protected discord guild.

You can see **all permissions** that need **2FA** (if enabled) on this official **Discord-Developer Documentation** site: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#permissions-bitwise-permission-flags